# How to identify a Nietzschean?

Tags: andromeda

In the television series Andromeda, there was a race of humanoids called Nietzscheans which looked human.  How did characters know which were human and which were Nietzscheans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nietzscheans have "[bone blades](https://www.google.de/search?safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1141&bih=604&q=%20Nietzscheans%20bone%20blades&oq=%20Nietzscheans%20bone%20blades&gs_l=img.3...1323.7650.0.8171.22.7.2.13.14.0.327.988.1j0j2j1.4.0....0...1ac.1j2.64.img..4.4.696.0..0j35i39k1j0i19k1.CTrLLDuPBtM)" protruding from their wrists.

Also shouting "Hey, homo sapiens" might work - if your head gets ripped off to avenge the insult then you have probably met a Nietzschean.

Comment: Dam, watching too many Star Trek alien lifeforms with different ridges to their heads, I take didn't look elsewhere for clues.